# Questions in queue showed as "Modified" when in the "Newest" tab instead of "Active"

Tags: bug, question-lists

This is the 2nd time I've noticed this happen (to me) in the past few days, where questions I follow in the "php" section of Stack Overflow that shows "Modified X mins ago" with the photo of the person who modified the question.

The odd thing is that, it showed it to me when I was in the "Newest" tab and expected them to show as being modified if I were in the "Active" tab which I was not in, nor did go from "Newest" to "Active" and vice-versa.

I thought I'd post this as a possible bug. I am unsure if this has already been seen and asked already.

**NOTE:** I did not click on anything at all. It appeared/changed itself on its own.

See the screenshot that I saved:

[image]

---

**Edit:** It's still happening. I noticed the same behaviour again just now and yesterday.

Comment: @Kaiido It does not. There was [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/343767/x-questions-with-new-activity-showing-incorrect-information-in-windows-with-mu) that seems to fit the bill though.

Comment: How come it doesn't? That's exactly the same (new) issue that "newest" tab shows "modified" and "answered" event. The auto comment is bad here because on meta dupes don't have to "answer" the current question. The same bug reports are still dupes, even if not fixed yet.

Comment: @Kaiido You could be right. I may have gotten confused with them probably clicking from one tab to another and it did that. For me, it showed it to me without my reloading that queue page, that I find rather weird. Well, if it gets closed as a duplicate, it will be ok.

Comment: I agree with @Kaiido this is the same issue and if you want to reproduce it stay on the newset tab and don't click the notification for a good moment then click on it and if any of the new questions are modified or answered you will see this.

Comment: @TemaniAfif True yet I didn't click on anything and it showed up by itself. So to me, that seems to probably be a JS script or something similar causing it to do that. I can't really "what" exactly since I don't know how their architecture is setup.